# How to update the snippet.description on Youtube from Google Apps Script API using only the videoId?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to update my `snippet.description` on my Youtube channel using the API exposed through Google Apps Script. I know the `videoId` already so there is no need to create and loop through a search list like they [show in the example here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script#update_video).

I expect to see my script complete with the new description on my Youtube video. But I get the following error message instead.

> API call to youtube.videos.update failed with error: Forbidden (line 90, file "Youtube")

Code.gs

```
function updateVideo( data ) {
  var videoId = 'foo';
  var title = 'bar';
  var description = 'baz';
  var resource = {
    id: videoId,
    snippet: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      categoryId: '22'
    }
  };
  YouTube.Videos.update(resource, 'id,snippet'); // this is line 90
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Note

To clarify: By "only the `videoId`", I mean without creating a list of channels to find it [like they do here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script#update_video).

```
var myChannels = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});
```

#### Edit

This question is different because the other asks specifically about HTML. This question is not about using HTML in the description. It's about making any changes whatsoever to the description.

Comment: I think that your script works. From the error message, I think that the video ID might be not correct. So can you confirm it again? The video ID is `###` of `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=###`. If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: This clearly seems to be an authorization error... Is the primary YouTube account of the logged-in user the owner of the video you are trying to modify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update HTML of Youtube video snippet description from the API exposed through Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039711/how-to-update-html-of-youtube-video-snippet-description-from-the-api-exposed-thr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments:

This is an authorization error. The account making the API request was not the same account as the owner of the YouTube video.