# How to update HTML of Youtube video snippet description from the API exposed through Google Apps Script?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to update my Youtube video `snippet.description` from the API exposed through Google Apps Script. The snippet contains formatting so I am trying to use HTML. I expect to see the updated snippet on my Youtube video. But I get the following error instead.

> API call to youtube.videos.update failed with error: The request metadata specifies an invalid video description. (line 88, file "Youtube")

How can I format my video description?

Youtube.gs

```
function updateVideo( data ) {
  var videoId = 'foo';
  var title = 'bar';
  var description = '<p>baz</p><p>bat</p>';
  var resource = {
    id: videoId,
    snippet: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      categoryId: '22'
    }
  };
  YouTube.Videos.update(resource, 'id,snippet'); // this is line 88
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HTML so you have to use string symbols for newline `\n` and tab `\t`, etc.

```
var description = 'baz\n\nbat';
```

I don't know how to add other HTML features like links, etc. Maybe someone else can improve upon this answer by adding that information if they know how to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, HTML tags cannot be used for the description. But, when you want to add the LINK, please directly put the URL. In this case, the URL can be accessed by clicking the link. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.